# Simple product with multiple images for showing sides

Tags: products, gallery

Hope you will be fine. I am a newbie in Magento. I am really stuck here.

There are about 50 Simple Products in my store. Everything is fine. I just want to show multiple images (different sides: front, side, back) of my simple products. But right now, I can show only 1 picture. Is there any way to show multiple images for simple product in magento?

Please do not recommend "Configurable Products". I do not want to create all of my products again.

Please help!

In case of any question, please ask. I will be happy to hear :)

Anxiously waiting for any response.

Answer (score 1):

This is already possible by uploading multiple images in the gallery. To upload multiple images:

1. Go to the images tab of the simple product
2. Click on *Browse Files...* and select all the images you want.
3. Hit *Upload Files*.
4. Once files are uploaded, you can choose which image to make base, small and thumbnail by clicking on the corresponding radio buttons. No brainier here.
5. Hit save.

You should be able to see the default gallery on the front end for that simple product.

Comment: Dear Sir, 
Many thanks for your answer but the problem is a bit different. I have added 4 images for a product. and set on of them as "Base Image" , "Small image" etc. these are working fine but I cant show more than 1 image on cart. I am attaching screenshots for magento backend, gallery and cart for you reference.

Comment: Dear Sam, 
Many thanks for your answer but the problem is a bit different. I have added 4 images for a product. These are working fine but I cant show more than 1 image on cart. I am attaching screenshots for magento backend, gallery and cart for you reference. I want to show multiple image on cart page. here are links for screenshots. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vs9JEa2VdNTHBubkVFaVJGMzQ/edit?usp=sharing)  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vs9JEa2VdNQUdiNkZwUFhNZFU/edit?usp=sharing)   [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vs9JEa2VdNLW5qOTFwYThOUmc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks like you have modified the template to not show the gallery on the product detail page. It does not matter if the product is simple or configurable, if the product has multiple images and you have not modified the template files, you should see the other images too. Look for the lines `if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 1):` in media.phtml in your template/catalog/product/view folder.

Comment: Dear Sam, Many thanks for your help. Actually, it is my friend's store. He has told me now that he hired someone in past to make some amendments. I have compared website with demo of theme. there are many changes. I have got a new copy of theme and replaced the media.phtml file but No luck. Can you please identify any other file that can be replaced a multiple images can be shown. Will be verrryyy.. thankful to you. Regards

Comment: Dear Sam, Right now, the piece of code in media.phtml is     'code'<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
'code'

Comment: It is difficult to fix this without looking at the code. It is possible the gallery is hidden by javaScript or CSS, or the media.phtml file you are looking at is the wrong one (look at frontend/YourCustomTheme instead of frontend/base folders.)